# Biometric Authentication fails after app updates

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication

So, i've implemented biometric authentication in my app using AndroidX.BiometricPrompt system it works fine, but when the app updates from GooglePlay, the biometric login gets invalid.

- The user data is saved in a SQLite table, was not my choice, its a boss demand;
- When the user inserts his login/password for the first time it shows a prompt with a switch that changes a bool "isBiometricAuthorized" on the db to true and it binds the login with the device biometric credentials if the user wants to;
- Theres no migrations related to the user data and im not sure if after the app updates from GooglePlay it cleans its caches automatically.

```kotlin
 
    private lateinit var executor: Executor
    private lateinit var biometricPrompt: BiometricPrompt
    private lateinit var promptInfo: BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo

        executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)
        biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(this, executor,
            object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                    result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                    super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                    startLogin(null, true)
                }

                override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                    super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            })

 private fun getCancellationSignal() : CancellationSignal {
        cancellationSignal = CancellationSignal()
        cancellationSignal?.setOnCancelListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Canceled by the user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        return  cancellationSignal as CancellationSignal
    }

    private fun checkBiometricSupport() : Boolean {
        var canAuthenticate = true
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 29) {
                val keyguardManager : KeyguardManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
                val packageManager : PackageManager   = applicationContext.packageManager
                if(!packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT)) {
                    canAuthenticate = false
                }
                if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure) {
                    canAuthenticate = false
                }
            } else {
                canAuthenticate = true
            }
        }else{
            canAuthenticate = false
        }
        return canAuthenticate
    }


    private fun startBioLogin() {
        UiHelper.hideSoftKeyboard(this)
        promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Biometric Authentication")
            .setSubtitle("How you wish to authenticate?")
            .setDescription("Its the fastest way to acess the system")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
            .build()

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
    }
```

Comment: The biometric authentication (using AndroidX.BiometricPrompt system) is independent of any app, means as long as the stored fingerprint(s) stay unchanged the "onAuthenticationSucceeded" listener will be called with "true". IMHO the business logic in your app sets the database entry back to "not authorized by fingerprint" when updating.